# When you execute chrome browser using Chrome DevTools Protocol, where does such session store stuff like history, cookies and extensions added?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I realized today that you can merge `Chrome DevTools Protocol` with `Selenium` in order to automate some very specific parts of a process within a website.

*for instance: after some initial conditions have met, automate the process of uploading some files to an account and etc...*

According to the [official repository](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) you use a sentence like the following on `cmd` to create a new chrome session with your user data:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir:"C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
```

So in my case, the sentence above generates the following output:

[image: preview1]

The thing is, in my original session I had some `Chrome extensions` added, and I know that If I were to work only with `Selenium` using its `chromedriver.exe`, I could easily add an extension (which must be compressed as a `.crx` file) by using the following sentence:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options
opt.add_extension(fr'{extension_path}')
```

But it seems that `Chrome DevTools Protocol` can't just add as much `Options` as `Selenium`, so I would have to install all my extensions in this pseudo session of mine again, no problem.

But, **after installing such extensions**, will those keep installed and ready for use after I execute again `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir:"C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"`, and if so, where?

Or if not, does that mean that I would have to re install those every single time I need to do tests with `Chrome DevTools Protocol` and my `Chrome extensions`? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can confirm, a session opened with `Chrome DevTools Protocol` somehow stores permanently the extensions you re installed. It also remembers if you used some specific credentials for logging in to some sites.